# How to return a single group from a panda dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe with goal scorers and I would like to extract the top scoring group into an array. This group can contain more than one items (in the example below there are two players with 8 goals).

So in the example below it would result in an array like this:

```
[{'goals': 8, 'name': 'Sergio Agüero', 'team': 'Manchester City'}, {'goals': 8, 'name': 'Tammy Abraham', 'team': 'Chelsea'}]
```

---

```
import pandas as pd 

data = [
    {
        "name": "Sergio Ag\u00fcero",
        "team": "Manchester City",
        "goals": "8"
    },
    {
        "name": "Tammy Abraham",
        "team": "Chelsea",
        "goals": "8"
    },
    {
        "name": "Pierre-Emerick Aubameyang",
        "team": "Arsenal",
        "goals": "7"
    },
    {
        "name": "Raheem Sterling",
        "team": "Manchester City",
        "goals": "6"
    },
    {
        "name": "Teemu Pukki",
        "team": "Norwich",
        "goals": "6"
    }
]

top_scorers = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=["name", "team", "goals"])

top_scoring_group = top_scorers.groupby("goals")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC,

```
(top_scorers[top_scorers['goals'].eq(top_scorers['goals'].max())]
     .to_dict('rows')
)
```

Output:

```
[{'name': 'Sergio Agüero', 'team': 'Manchester City', 'goals': '8'},
 {'name': 'Tammy Abraham', 'team': 'Chelsea', 'goals': '8'}]
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
top_scoring_group = top_scorers.groupby("team", as_index=False)['goals'].sum().nlargest(1, 'goals', keep='all')['team']
```

This will get the teams with most goals, and keep them all if there are more than one.

Comment: I'm getting this error:

ValueError: keep must be either "first", "last"

Also, the groupby should be on goals, not teams. And it would be great if the end result was an array as shown in the beginning of question.

Comment: From [the docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.nlargest.html) for pandas v0.25.2, keep must be either  {‘first’, ‘last’, ‘all’}, default ‘first’. For the groupby, I misunderstood your question.